# What does "transport-based" mean?

Tags: networking, socket.io, engine.io

On the engine.io [website](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1) it says:

> Engine.IO is the implementation of transport-based
>   cross-browser/cross-device bi-directional communication layer for
>   Socket.IO.

What does "transport-based" mean? I presume simply that it uses TCP?

Answer (score 1):

It means the ability to use different underlying transports to support the Socket.IO api.  The two core transports that it uses are polling: XHR / JSONP polling transport, and websocket: WebSocket.

From the docs:

> The main premise of Engine, and the core of its existence, is the
>   ability to swap transports on the fly. A connection starts as
>   xhr-polling, but it can switch to WebSocket.
>
> The central problem this poses is: how do we switch transports without
>   losing messages?

Located [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#architecture)